# Substitutions in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I’m trying to write a function with two arguments of this type:

```
substitutions (list_one, list_two)
```

list_one has always this form (letters can change according to the input):

```
(1 ((1 2 ((1 2 r) (3 2 t) (4 3 c))) (3 4 ((5 6 y) (5 7 i)))))
```

list_two has always this form (numbers can change according to the input):

```
(2 3 4 5 6)
```

I want to substitute in this way:

```
r-> 2
t -> 3
c -> 4
y -> 5
i -> 6
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. You have to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself. Post your code and then we'll help you understand what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: How does it know which letters map to which numbers? Is it just that the first letter in `list_1` gets the first number in `list_two`, the second letter gets the second number, and so on?

Comment: I tried in every way and I failed so I decided to ask here! My problem is the more-than.one level list.

Comment: That means you need to write a recursive function.

Comment: Yes it is just that the first letter in list_1 gets the first number in list_two, the second letter gets the second number, and so on

Comment: I know recursion but the problem is the more than one level list

Comment: That's the whole point of using recursion. When there's a nested list, you call the function on it, so that goes down to the next level.

Comment: I know but... how to say that I have to substitute the first letter (of the first list in the first list of the first list) which the car of the list, and so on and then  the first letter (of the first list in the first list of the second list) not with the rest of the second_list but with the first number from which I leaved in the previous substitution?

Comment: Remove the first element from `list_two` whenever you do a substitution.

Comment: I don't think your answers are useful

Comment: Please if you don't have idea of how to help me stop answering in this way

Comment: This is obviously a school assignment. I'm trying to guide you towards figuring it out yourself, not just give you the answer, because that's the way you'll really learn.

Comment: Say "use recursion" or "delete the first element of list_2" are not answers!! Are obviously ideas already tried... we learn this things in the first two lessons! The problem here is more difficult

Comment: I know they're not answers, I didn't post them in the Answer section. They're intended to be hints to you to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

A not so efficient solution is to first find a list of all the letters in the fist tree structure (the first list) and then to LOOP over the results calling SUBST repeatedly.

To find the list of non numeric atoms in the first list (the 'letters') you need to traverse the tree structure (le first list) recurring both on the FIRST and on the REST of the list.

Hope it helps.

MA

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are proper you can iterate them with the `loop` macro and pop off the arguments in the accessible free variable:

```
(defun template-replace (template replacements)
  (labels ((iterate (template)
             (loop :for element :in template
                   :collect
                   (cond ((consp element) (iterate element))
                         ((symbolp element) (pop replacements))
                         (t element)))))
    (iterate template)))


(template-replace '(1 rep (4 rep (9 rep)) rep) '(foot inch mm multiplied))
; ==> (1 foot (4 inch (9 mm)) multiplied)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But.. Is there another way in order to do the same thing not using labels and : arguments?

Comment: @Raynold There are always ways to do it more constricted, but why would you want to solve it in a more difficult and perhaps suboptimal manner? A hint would be to do it recursively and it needs to return two values. The result and the leftover replacements. if template is `consp` then use `multiple-value-bind` to  get the results from the `car` so that you can do the `cdr`. In the rest you have to handle returning the arguments if the element is not a symbol and null while you return the first and the rest of the replacements for the rest.